# Suppressing comma in one index entry

Tags: punctuation, indexing

I have a line that says ``` \index{flamingo's ``knee''} ```. As one would expect, it produces an entry

> flamingo’s “knee”, 3

in the index. Unfortunately the publisher wants it to be

> flamingo’s “knee,” 3

and I haven’t succeeded in getting that. If I change ``` \index{flamingo's ``knee''} ``` to ``` \index{flamingo's ``knee,''} ``` I get two commas:

> flamingo’s “knee,”, 3

How can I get rid of the second comma in this entry only, while not affecting any entries that don’t contain quotation marks?

Answer (score 11):

Interesting question!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\newrobustcmd{\invertcomma}[2]{#2#1}

\begin{document}

Flamingo's ``knee''\index{flamingosknee@flamingo's ``knee\invertcomma{''}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but misguided publisher.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Certainly so!

Comment: I have a question that is similar, but different. I want to index the name of a book that ends in a question mark. What I get is \textit{What is Life?}, 27, but what I'd like is \textit{What is Life?} 27. In other words I want to suppress the comma. Only when I've succeeded in doing it will I know if it looks better like that.

Comment: @Athel This should be a new question.